# Must-have (noun) alternatives

Tags: phrase-requests, synonyms

The noun 'must-have' is defined in the Cambridge Dictionary as:

> Something that many people want to own.

Do you know any alternatives for expressing the same meaning? I would like to use it to make the writing a bit more elegant: 'must-have' sounds so cliché-ish.

I'm open to synonyms (Thesaurus had none) and phrases.

The more it leans to 'vital' to own instead of 'want' to own, the better.

Comment: sine qua non, requisite, necessity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more proper word is *essentials*. [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/essential) defines it as:

> a basic, indispensable, or necessary element; chief point:
>   *Concentrate on essentials rather than details.*

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/essential) says:

> A thing that is absolutely necessary.
>   *‘we only had the bare essentials in the way of equipment’*